Material Icons didn‘t show on my Avalonia Project
I add Material.Icons.Avalonia Nuget package to my Avalonia MVVM project,however,when I try to show a icon on my button component,it doesn't work,and nothing showed on my button.
Here are code with problems.
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="using:SharpDesktop.ViewModels"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:materialIcons="clr-namespace:Material.Icons.Avalonia;assembly=Material.Icons.Avalonia"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="SharpDesktop.Views.MainWindow"
        x:DataType="vm:MainWindowViewModel"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="SharpDesktop"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        ExtendClientAreaToDecorationsHint="True"
        ExtendClientAreaChromeHints="NoChrome"
        ExtendClientAreaTitleBarHeightHint="-1">

    <Design.DataContext>
        <!-- This only sets the DataContext for the previewer in an IDE,
             to set the actual DataContext for runtime, set the DataContext property in code (look at App.axaml.cs) -->
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Design.DataContext>

    <!--内容区域-->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- 标题栏 -->
        <Border Grid.Row="0"
            Height="60"
            Background="Pink"
            x:Name="TitleBar"
            Padding="16"
            >
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                <DockPanel Dock="Right">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button>
                            <materialIcons:MaterialIcon Kind="ExitRun"/>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DockPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>

        <!-- 内容区域 -->
        <Border Grid.Row="1">
            
        </Border>
    </Grid>

</Window>

Show the apperance
I checked my application configuration , and find nothing.
<Application xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Class="SharpDesktop.App"
             xmlns:local="using:SharpDesktop"
             xmlns:themes="clr-namespace:Material.Styles.Themes;assembly=Material.Styles"
             xmlns:dialogHost="clr-namespace:DialogHostAvalonia;assembly=DialogHost.Avalonia"
             xmlns:materialIcons="clr-namespace:Material.Icons.Avalonia;assembly=Material.Icons.Avalonia"
             RequestedThemeVariant="Default">
    <!-- "Default" ThemeVariant follows system theme variant. "Dark" or "Light" are other available options. -->

    <Application.DataTemplates>
        <local:ViewLocator/>
    </Application.DataTemplates>

    <Application.Styles>
        <themes:MaterialTheme BaseTheme="Dark" PrimaryColor="Purple" SecondaryColor="Lime"/>
        <materialIcons:MaterialIconStyles/>
        <materialIcons:MaterialIconExt/>
    </Application.Styles>
</Application>

Also I checked my nuget packages,they are installed perfectly.
